# How to debug referenced project in Monodroid?

Tags: debugging, xamarin.android

I am developing monodroid with Visual Studio 2010.

I have a .net library containing the business logic and my monodroid application. In the monodroid application i use the business logic library. (Add reference...) When i debug know and want to step into a method call that goes to the library the step is just skipped by the debugger and i continue in the monodroid application.

Does anybody know a solution ? Like this it's really hard to develop...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just referencing a DLL, Visual Studio won't know about where to find the source for it normally and VS does not have a de-compiler built in. So you will need something like Reflector or link the project with the Business Logic into the Solution and use a project reference in the project you are debugging instead.

Comment: i am using a project reference